# Magento 2.4.4 - Call to a member function getCookieSecure() on null

Tags: cookie, magento2.2.4

After updating from 2.3.5 to 2.4.4-p2 I am getting an error when the frontend loads. This is how it looks, when I load the frontend: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1liN.png

The admin works just fine and there are no errors during cimpilation, upgrade or deployment. Any idea how to solve this? The error in the logs is: Error: Call to a member function getCookieSecure() on null in /vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/js/cookie.phtml:21

Running on PHP 8.1 and Magento 2.4.4.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Run this command `grep -r "js_cookies" app vendor` then edit your question to add the result.

Comment: Thanks this helped.I searched and checked that "js_cookies" was defined in default.xml in custom theme.

Comment: By removing it worked.

Comment: Great. Please add an answer about that and mark it as accepted to help other people who have the same issue.

Answer (score 4):

Finally, I found the solution.

Run the command `grep -r "js_cookies" app vendor` from Magento root directory to find any custom layout files that declared **js_cookies** block, then I found it declared in the `default.xml` in my custom theme.

Change the layout file from

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Js\Cookie" name="js_cookies" template="Magento_Theme::js/cookie.phtml"/>
```

to the following:

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Js\Cookie" name="js_cookies" template="Magento_Theme::js/cookie.phtml">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="session_config" xsi:type="object">Magento\Theme\ViewModel\Block\SessionConfig</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

In my case, I actually don't need to override that block from Magento default, so I removed it from the `default.xml` file, and it worked.

Comment: Perfect, thanks...!!!

Answer (score 0):

> First off: There isn't much information supplied to go with, so log files might guide you even better to the call stack.  Regardless, I will try to guide you and give some starting points for you to investigate.

For some reason your `sessionConfig` object is null which means some constructor initialization is not correctly setup. (It might be your overridden files (di.xml/the module/s) where dependency injection is not loading correctly.

I assume you did the following after deployment, but I add it here regardless.

*The important thing is to ensure you ran `bin/magento setup/di:compile` to **regenerate all processed code files***.

> (See dev:di:info discussion below)

```
rm -rf generated/code/*   // (this is to just ensure when you regenerate via setup/di:compile it can compile everything from scratch.

bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile  //(the important part)
bin/magento setup:static-content deploy
```

Comparing the templates from Magento 2.3 and 2.4:

[Magento 2.3 ~ html/cookie.phtml](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3/app/code/Magento/Cookie/view/base/templates/html/cookie.phtml)

[Magento 2.4 ~ html/cookie.phtml](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4/app/code/Magento/Cookie/view/base/templates/html/cookie.phtml)

There isn't much difference here:

> Magento 2.3

```
window.cookiesConfig.secure = <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getSessionConfig()->getCookieSecure() ? 'true' : 'false' ?>;
```

> Magento 2.4

```
$isCookieSecure = $block->getSessionConfig()->getCookieSecure() ? 'true' : 'false';
```

So the problem must be that `$block->getSessionConfig()` is null for some reason.

**If you still have a version 2.3.5 copy, you may want to *debug and put breakpoints* on the constructor, and compare to 2.4 version:**

**File** [Magento 2.3 \Cookie.php](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Element/Js/Cookie.php)

```
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        ConfigInterface $cookieConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\Validator\Ip $ipValidator,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->sessionConfig = $cookieConfig;
```

**File** [Magento 2.4 \Cookie.php](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Element/Js/Cookie.php):

```
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        ConfigInterface $cookieConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\Validator\Ip $ipValidator,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->sessionConfig = $cookieConfig;
```

This looks exactly the same, so Dependency Injection content (di.xml/layout configurations) is somehow broken.

`$cookieConfig` supplied to the constructor there should not be empty / null.

#### `dev:di:info` Information

`bin/magento dev:di:info` returns the constructor arguments for the requested class, most of which are configured via `di.xml` file somewhere.

The Class we are having issues with are `\Cookie` (and the `ConfigInterface` argument):

Run below to see arguments recognized by Magento 2 for your installation.

> **The below is on a Magento 2.3.7 installation**

> - `bin/magento dev:di:info "Magento\Framework\View\Element\Js\Cookie"`

```
bin/magento dev:di:info "Magento\Framework\View\Element\Js\Cookie"

DI configuration for the class Magento\Framework\View\Element\Js\Cookie in the GLOBAL area

Preference: Magento\Framework\View\Element\Js\Cookie

Constructor Parameters:
+--------------+--------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Name         | Requested Type                                   | Configured Value                                                         |
+--------------+--------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| context      | Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context  | {                                                                        |
|              |                                                  |     "_i_": "string Magento\\Framework\\View\\Element\\Template\\Context" |
|              |                                                  | }                                                                        |
| cookieConfig | Magento\Framework\Session\Config\ConfigInterface | {                                                                        |
|              |                                                  |     "_i_": "string Magento\\Framework\\Session\\Config"                  |
|              |                                                  | }                                                                        |
| ipValidator  | Magento\Framework\Validator\Ip                   | {                                                                        |
|              |                                                  |     "_i_": "string Magento\\Framework\\Validator\\Ip"                    |
|              |                                                  | }                                                                        |
| data         |                                                  | {                                                                        |
|              |                                                  |     "_v_": null                                                          |
|              |                                                  | }                                                                        |
+--------------+--------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+


Plugins:
+--------+--------+------+
| Plugin | Method | Type |
+--------+--------+------+


Plugins for the Preference:
+--------+--------+------+
| Plugin | Method | Type |
+--------+--------+------+
```

> - `bin/magento dev:di:info "Magento\Framework\Session\Config\ConfigInterface"`

```
bin/magento dev:di:info "Magento\Framework\Session\Config\ConfigInterface"

DI configuration for the class Magento\Framework\Session\Config\ConfigInterface in the GLOBAL area

Preference: Magento\Framework\Session\Config

Constructor Parameters:
+------------------+---------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+
| Name             | Requested Type                                    | Configured Value           |
+------------------+---------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+
| validatorFactory | Magento\Framework\ValidatorFactory                |                            |
| scopeConfig      | Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface |                            |
| stringHelper     | Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils              |                            |
| request          | Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface            |                            |
| filesystem       | Magento\Framework\Filesystem                      |                            |
| deploymentConfig | Magento\Framework\App\DeploymentConfig            |                            |
| scopeType        |                                                   |                            |
| lifetimePath     |                                                   | web/cookie/cookie_lifetime |
+------------------+---------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+


Plugins:
+--------+--------+------+
| Plugin | Method | Type |
+--------+--------+------+


Plugins for the Preference:
+--------+--------+------+
| Plugin | Method | Type |
+--------+--------+------+
```

**Compare your Magento 2.3 and 2.4 installations to see if you recognize any differences**.